# Regex to allow A-D, plus symbol, ' , and brackets

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex that takes in only A-D, plus symbol, ' , and brackets.

For example (A+B+C+D)(A+B)(A')

They must be all inside brackets for it to work but currently my regex allows terms outside the brackets to work too.

```
^[A-D\(\)\'+]+$
```

Need some help thanks

Comment: Your regex is fine. You don't need to escape the characters though, `^[A-D()'+]+$` should suffice.

Comment: Further ~proof that your regex is fine:  http://rubular.com/r/SdNXFzVuFm   and that you don't need to escape characters:  http://rubular.com/r/VHEMuYshtC

Comment: Try [`^(?:\([A-D]'?(?:\+[A-D]'?)*\))*$`](https://regex101.com/r/bj8b01/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work fine:

```
^(?:\([A-D]'?(?:\+[A-D]'?)*\))+$
```

Visit [this link](https://regex101.com/r/bAHSdf/2) to try out a working demo.

Answer (score 1):

In order to ensure everything is inside a pair of parenthesis (`()`), the parenthesis should not be inside the character class. Move them outside, and surround that with a repeating non-capturing group like this:

```
^(?:\([A-D'+]+\))+$
```

This will still allow A-D, plus signs, and single quotes to appear in any order inside parenthesis. If you don't want that, the regex will need to be changed to something like this:

```
^(?:\([A-D]+'?(?:\+[A-D]+'?)*\))+$
```

This will match the following:

```
(A)
(A')
(A+A)
(A'+A)
(A'+A')
```